# Here "It" refers to What?

Tags: pronouns, parts-of-speech, paraphrasing

My best friend is the man who in wishing me well wishes **it** for my sake.

By Aristotle

I think **"it"** refers to **wishes**, & it's a verb in this context and i want a rewriting of the sentence?

Comment: That sentence certainly isn't idiomatic, and I'd hazard a guess it's not syntactically valid in the first place. *My best friend is the man who in wishing me well **does so** for my sake.*

Comment: I doubt that Aristotle ever wrote in English...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, "it" is a pronoun replacing an idea.  Remember, a noun can be a person, place, thing, event, or *idea*--and, especially for the latter, it can be represented by an entire phrase or clause of text.

Here, the idea it represents is the well-wishes for me, i.e. "me well" in the example sentence.  Rewriting the sentence and substituting the pronoun for its antecedent will help clarify this.

*My best friend is the man who in wishing me well wishes **me well** for my sake.*

Comment: Can you write a paraphrase for this , plz..

Comment: You might say it as: "The man who wishes me well _for my sake_ is my best friend."  To my mind, the sentence implies that others may wish me well, but only for their own benefit--to make themselves appear good or polite, and it is only my best friend who wishes me well _for my_ benefit.

Answer (score 1):

In the above sentence, 'it' refers to the wishing me well.

The sentence could be rewritten as:
A man who wishes me well and who wishes me well for my sake, is my best friend.